# PHP Error: Call to undefined function module_list()

Tags: 7

In my servers Apache error log I regularly see the entry:

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function module_list() in /home/example/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 1074

Lines 1066 -> 1078 in bootstrap.inc are:

```
function bootstrap_invoke_all($hook) {
  // Bootstrap modules should have been loaded when this function is called, so
  // we don't need to tell module_list() to reset its internal list (and we
  // therefore leave the first parameter at its default value of FALSE). We
  // still pass in TRUE for the second parameter, though; in case this is the
  // first time during the bootstrap that module_list() is called, we want to
  // make sure that its internal cache is primed with the bootstrap modules
  // only.
  foreach (module_list(FALSE, TRUE) as $module) {
    drupal_load('module', $module);
    module_invoke($module, $hook);
  }
}
```

No errors appear in Drupal's Database logging. Today I have received some white screen 503s when checking the site and each time a new message appears in the Apache log. I have tried clearing caches and running `drush cc all`.

Does anyone has a suggestion as to what is causing this error or how to resolve it?

Some specifications about my set-up: PHP 5.5.12 (OPcache 7.0.4 as bundled), MariaDB 5.5.37, Apache HTTP 2.2.15, Centos 6.5 and Drupal 7.28. OPcache is 'Up and Running'.

To check if OPcache was the causing the problem I disabled it and monitored the error log. The error message still appears with OPcache disabled, and as it disabling it slows the site site significantly (in the region of 200ms > 600 ms) I have re-enabled.

Comment: APC/other opcode cache problem maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Clive, I have been looking into OPcache. I cannot find any bugs that produce similar errors which have not already been fixed in the current version. I have added specifications to my question in case this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: May be worth testing with an earlier PHP version as well, as 5.3 is recommended for D7 ( https://drupal.org/requirements )

Comment: As far as I can tell one of the main differences which causes issues between PHP 5.3 & 5.4+ is that OPcache is present. I am currently testing with OPcache disabled to see if it caused the error previously. I will let that test run for a while and if no change will swap down to PHP 5.3.

Comment: The error still occurs with OPcache disabled so I do not think it is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Do you perhaps use `page_cache_without_database` or do you have other cache-customization in place?

Comment: Znerol, yes I use memcache (memcache storage module) and did have `$conf['page_cache_without_database'] = TRUE;` set in my settings.php .  I did not have `$conf['page_cache_invoke_hooks'] = FALSE;` so have added it in and the error message has not appeared since. Thank you for the nudge/suggestion. If you would like to place as an answer I will gratefully accept, if not I will write it up for closure.

Comment: For posterity reasons posting we've found solution here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1215464

Comment: Try thinking differently about this. I had this problem, scoured the forums for a clue, but nothing was relevant to the solution, except that I read one person mention "update.php". So, I ran my website.com/update.php and got a MySQL login error. It would appear that the website copied to a new domain, the db_user/db_password didn't even exist on the new server (a GoDaddy shared hosting). I created the same username/password as in my sites/defaults/setting.php, and then I assigned that new user to the correct db in cPanel. If it fails 1st time, generate a new pwd & save it. Now the site works.

Comment: One more change I made was I found on line 345 in sites/all/module/domain/domain.bootstrap.in this line: `if (strpos($cookie_domain, 'www.') === 0) {` to which I added an else if because I was using a different subdomain: `else if (strpos($cookie_domain, 'current.') === 0) {
        $cookie_domain = substr($cookie_domain, 8);
      }` Be sure to change the number value in the substr function to whatever the length of your subdomain is, plus 1.

Comment: I had the same problem and I fixed by fixing the database connection details.